# Python 3 robotparser errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, robots.txt

I have next robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*/feed
Disallow: /*/trackback
Disallow: /category/
Disallow: /forum/
Disallow: /program/
Disallow: /wp-content/
Disallow: /trafficsystem/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /*?
Disallow: /*.css$
Disallow: /author/
Disallow: /*/?replytocom
Disallow: /privacy/
Disallow: /terms/
Disallow: /copyright/
Disallow: /*/users/
Disallow: /*/topic-tag/
Disallow: /quick-share/
```

I use python 3.4.3 and robotparser 
When I call can_fetch to disallowed page it returns True:

```
can_fetch("*", "http://example.com/2008/04/10/8-reasons-i-am-successful-and-you-are-not/?replytocom=154237")
```

Why?

Comment: Sorry for my English :(